# quitar linea vertical al final de texto

Tags: html, css, text

Hola me gustaria saber como se llama esa linea vertical y si se puede quitar
Muchas gracias. soy nuevo en esto. Saludos

[[image: Quitar la linea negra vertical]][]

Comment: Cuál es el código o etiquetas que usas para eso?

Comment: Bienvenido Thony herrera. Deberías de pasarte por la ayuda https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. 
Sin ponernos nada de código nos va a ser difícil de responderte

Comment: Situa el ratón sobre esa línea, pulsa sobre el boton derecho del mismo, y selecciona "Inspeccionar" en el menú contextual que aparece.  Eso te abrirá el inspector de objetos en ese punto exacto y accederás al código HTML que necesitamos que nos copies y pegues en tu pregunta para poderte ayudar.  A ciegas solo se me ocurre que eso sea un `border` de algun tipo de elemento común entre ambos textos.

Comment: hola muchas gracias justamente era un border que habia dejado y no me di cuenta muchas gracias a todos y tambien vi que se llama algo asi como pay, pey, pai, no se muy bien aun